# Logic Error in Aligning of Outputs, Search and Edit in a Student Record Program

Tags: c++, arrays, search, file-io, edit

I really need some help and any suggestions would be appreciated.
In the alignment of outputs, the characters move once an excess character was involved. I was hoping that the program will output in one place regardless of how many characters there are. I tried cout.width() but no avail. In the search function, the search works once you entered the ID of the student you first registered but once you entered the second student, It  can not detect the second student but it can still detect the first student. In the Edit function, I am stuck at the Check ID and cannot proceed to editing and I tried copying some codes from the net but to no avail because they are using public and class and not structure. There is some warning that says "234   48  [Warning] ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second:" but the program still works and it will be set aside for now.

```
#include<iostream>


//fstream is needed because we will use file systems.
#include<fstream>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

/*declaring fstream global variable used
  to open, write, read and close files in this program.*/
fstream storage;


struct student_profile{
    char FName[100];
    char LName[100];
    char reg_year[100];
    char course[100];
    char id[100];
    int no_courses;
    char course_Name[100];
    char course_code[100];
    int credit_hour;
    int quiz_one;
    int quiz_two;
    int quiz_three;
    int mid;
    int assignment;
    int lab;
    int final_exam;
    char ID[100];
};



/* creating structure variable from student_profile.
   the name this structure variable is student.
   it is used to hold name, last name, id etc
*/
student_profile student;


/* function used to register student.
   it accept student details then it write those data to file.
   so student details will be saved in text file for later use.
*/
void function_to_register(){
 cout<<"        Write First Name of student: ";
 cin>>student.FName;
 cout<<"        Write Last Name of student: ";
 cin>>student.LName;
 cout<<"        Write Registration year: ";
 cin>>student.reg_year;
 cout<<"        Write Course of student: ";
 cin>>student.course;
 cout<<"        Write number of courses that student learns in this semester and register them one by one\n";
 cout<<"        Number of courses: ";
 cin>> student.no_courses;
 cout <<"       Write ID: ";
 cin>>student.ID;


/* for loop used to register multiple courses for one student
   based on the student's number of courses entered.
 */
 for(int a=1; a<=student.no_courses; a++) {
 cout<<"         Write course Name: ";
 cin>>student.course_Name;
 cout<<"         Enter grade for quiz one: ";
 cin>>student.quiz_one;
 cout<<"         Enter grade for quiz two: ";
 cin>>student.quiz_two;
 cout<<"         Enter grade for quiz three: ";
 cin>>student.quiz_three;
 cout<<"         Enter midterm grade: ";
 cin>>student.mid;
 cout<<"         Enter assignment grade: ";
 cin>>student.assignment;
 cout<<"         Enter lab grade: ";
 cin>>student.lab;
 cout<<"         Enter final exam grade: ";
 cin>>student.final_exam;
 storage.open("marklist.txt",ios::app) ;
   storage.write((char*)&student, sizeof(student));
   //storage.write(student,sizeof(student));
 storage.close();
 }
}


 /* function used to calculate grade of each course.
    we call this function when the program is displaying grade of student.
 */
void grade_calculator(int totalMark) {
    if(totalMark>=90 && totalMark<=100)
        cout<<"A+";
    else if(totalMark>=80 && totalMark<90)
        cout<<"A";
    else if(totalMark>=70 && totalMark<80)
        cout<<"B";
    else if(totalMark>=60 && totalMark<70)
        cout<<"C+";
    else if(totalMark>=50 && totalMark<60)
        cout<<"D";
    else if(totalMark>=0 && totalMark<50)
        cout<<"F";
    else
        cout<<"NG";
    }


/* function used to display registered students on the screen.
   this function gets the registered student from that file
   we used above to store student details.
*/
void seeRegistered() {
 storage.open("marklist.txt",ios::app);
 storage.close();

 storage.open("marklist.txt",ios::in);
 storage.read((char*)&student, sizeof(student));

 while (storage.eof()==0) {
  cout<<"\n\n\n";
  cout<<"  Full Name: "<<student.FName<<"  "<<student.LName<<endl;
  cout<<"  ID: "<<student.ID<<endl;
  cout<<"  Registration Year: "<<student.reg_year<<endl;
  cout<<"  Faculty: "<<student.course<<endl;
  cout<<"  *****************************************************************************\n";
  cout<<"  ******************************STUDENT MARK LIST******************************\n";
  cout<<"  *****************************************************************************\n";
  cout<<"  Subject    Quiz1   Quiz2   Quiz3    Mid   Assignment    Final   Total   Grade\n";
  cout<<"  _____________________________________________________________________________\n";


/* for loop used to print all courses and their marks
   for a single student.
*/
     for(int t=1; t<=student.no_courses; t++) {
        int totalMark;
        totalMark= (student.quiz_one+student.quiz_two+student.quiz_three+student.assignment+student.mid+student.final_exam) / 6;
        cout.width(2); cout<<""<<student.course_Name;
        cout.width(7); cout<<""<<student.quiz_one;
        cout.width(6); cout<<""<<student.quiz_two;
        cout.width(6); cout<<""<<student.quiz_three;
        cout.width(7); cout<<""<<student.mid;
        cout.width(4); cout<<""<<student.assignment;
        cout.width(12); cout<<""<<student.final_exam;
        cout.width(6); cout<<""<<totalMark<<"      ";
        cout <<" ";grade_calculator(totalMark);
        cout<<endl;
        storage.read((char*)&student,sizeof(student));
     }
  }
storage.close();
}


void searchStudent(){
    

std::string  search;

    cout<<"Please enter your ID"<< endl;
    cin>>search;
    storage.open("marklist.txt", ios::in);
    storage.read((char*)&student,sizeof(student));
    
        while (storage.eof()==0)
        {
            if(student.ID==search)
            {
                  cout<<"\n\n\n";
              cout<<"  Full Name: "<<student.FName<<"  "<<student.LName<<endl;
                cout<<"  ID: "<<student.ID<<endl;
              cout<<"  Registration Year: "<<student.reg_year<<endl;
              cout<<"  Faculty: "<<student.course<<endl;
              cout<<"  *****************************************************************************\n";
              cout<<"  ******************************STUDENT MARK LIST******************************\n";
              cout<<"  *****************************************************************************\n";
              cout<<"  Subject    Quiz1   Quiz2   Quiz3    Mid   Assignment    Final   Total   Grade\n";
              cout<<"  _____________________________________________________________________________\n";
                    for(int t=1; t<=student.no_courses; t++) {
                        int totalMark;
                                cout.width(2); cout<<""<<student.course_Name;
                                cout.width(7); cout<<""<<student.quiz_one;
                                cout.width(6); cout<<""<<student.quiz_two;
                                cout.width(6); cout<<""<<student.quiz_three;
                                cout.width(7); cout<<""<<student.mid;
                                cout.width(4); cout<<""<<student.assignment;
                                cout.width(12); cout<<""<<student.final_exam;
                                cout.width(6); cout<<""<<totalMark<<"      ";
                                cout <<" ";grade_calculator(totalMark);
                                cout<<endl;
     }
 }
            else{
                cout<< "\n\n***************Student not found***************\n\n"<<endl;
            }
            break;
        }
    storage.read((char*)&student, sizeof(student));
    
    storage.close();

}
void editStudent(){
    system("cls");
    char checkID[100];
    cout <<"Enter Student ID: ";
    cin >> checkID;
    
    storage.open("marklist.txt",ios::in|ios::out);
    storage.read((char*)&student,sizeof(student));
    
    while (storage.eof()==0);
    {
        if (student.ID==checkID)
        {
            cout << "Name: " <<student.FName <<" " <<student.LName <<endl;
            cout << "Registration Year: " <<student.reg_year <<endl;
            cout << "Course: "<<student.no_courses <<endl;
            cout << "ID: " <<student.ID<<endl;
            cout <<"\n Enter New Name: ";
            cin >>student.FName;
            cout <<"\n Enter New Last Name: ";
            cin>>student.LName;
            cout <<"\n Enter New Registration Year: ";
            cin>>student.reg_year;
            cout<<"\n Enter New Course: ";
            cin>>student.course;
            cout<<"\n Enter New ID: ";
            cin >>student.ID;
            
            
            storage.seekp(storage.tellg()-sizeof(student));
            storage.write((char*)&student,sizeof(student));
            cout<<"\n\n File Updated";
        }
            else{
                cout<<"ID not found"<<endl;
            
        }
        storage.read((char*)&student,sizeof(student));
        
    }
    storage.close();
    
}
/* This is the main function which will be  executed before all functions,
   So in this program when the user select one option then by
   the help switch statement the user redirects to appropriate function.
 */


 int main() {
 char select;

/* while loop that help us to excute the program all time.
   this means the program will not exit without our interest.*/
 while(1) {
  cout<<endl; cout<<endl; cout<<endl;
  cout<<endl;
  cout<<"     **********************************************\n";
  cout<<"     *  STUDENT REGISTRATION AND MARK LIST SYSTEM *\n";
  cout<<"     **********************************************\n";
  cout<<"     *\n";
  cout<<"     Enter 1 To Register New student \n";
  cout<<"     Enter 2 To Show Registerd Students and Their Grade \n";
              /*
                you can improve this in which the displayed record is sorted (ascending/descending)
                */
  cout<<"     Enter 3 To Search for a student \n";
  cout<<"     Enter 4 To Edit a student record\n";
  cout<<"     Enter 5 To Delete a student record\n";

  cout<<"     Enter 0 To Exit \n";
  cout<<"     : ";
  cin>>select;

  switch (select) {
        case '1':
            function_to_register();
            cout<<"          Student Registered successfully \n";
           break;
        case '2':
     seeRegistered();
            break;
        case '3':
            searchStudent();
            break;
        case '4':
            editStudent();
            cout<<"\n\nStudent Profile Updated Successfully"<<endl;
            break;
        case '0':
        exit(0);
        
            
     

  }
 }

}
```

Comment: In C++ it's very important to use `std::string` as it avoids a lot of the suffering and abject misery that is C strings.

Comment: I fixed the alignment problem using the cout<<setw()